# Webpage not finding style sheet

Tags: python, html, css, django

For some reason beyond me my html page is not finding my stylesheet. I'm using the Django framework if that helps at all. I'm running it on a localhost currently.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../fitness/templates/masterpage.css"  type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<h1> MasterPage</h1>



{% block content %} {% endblock %} 
</body>
</html>
```

masterpage.css

```
h1 {
color: #fff;

}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: What do Firebug or Google's developer tools say about the exact path of the CSS file that is being loaded? (in the "Net" tab)

Comment: the firebug is finding the correct path i think  (localhost:8000/fitness/templates/), however it says there are no rules inside.

Comment: Can you click the URL and see whether the actual style sheet turns up?

Comment: Why is your CSS in the templates directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serving static files, like CSS, django has the staticfiles lib:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ - development version
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/ - Django 1.4
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/ - Django 1.3

Note that this requires a recent version of Django, as it's a quite recent addition

My guess is that the URL of the CSS matches no patterns in your urls.py, and thus returns an error

Answer (score 0):

According to css link your paths may be:

> [same root]/fitness/templates
>
> [same root]/[maybe something else?]/current (the one that has the
> displayed html)

Seeing your comment (answer) to Chris I suggest you to change the css link to:

> /fitness/templates/masterpage.css

and ensure that you have masterpage.css under the corresponding physical path

Answer (score 0):

The SHORT ANSWER HERE: In your settings.py make sure that you set a folder for STATIC_DIRS, a STATIC_URL (usually just '/static/'). Set a STATIC_ROOT setting of myproject/static/. Leave this folder empty. Add one folder under STATIC_DIRS call it myprojet/assets/. Then in assets/ have css, img, and js. Now you can access all assets in these organized folders via this location no matter what folder its in. {{ STATIC_URL }}/main.css  {{ STATIC_URL }}/banner.png Also as a last resort run python manage.py collectstatic at your shell, and make sure that in your settings.py you have uncommented Django's static file handlers. (They are uncommented by default.)

Django Best Practices THE LONG ANSWER READ ONWARDS(in my limited experience).

Since they introduced the STATIC_DIRS { } setting I have always left the myproject/static/ directory empty. (During deployment it will be necessary to run python manage.py collectstatic command on your server to collect all of the admin files from site-packages and other things that your static server will be serving. So leave it empty for all that mess that goes in there later. Use a different folder for your "assets".)

I have a directory called src, many call it media also at the project level. Django 1.4 project level with manage.py not with your settings.py. I add myproject/src/ to the STATIC_DIRS setting. It is a tuple that should contain strings. Inside the src/ directory I have js, img, css. The coolest thing about all of the STATIC_DIRS you may decide to create is they can all be accessed via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/main.css" />
```

Note: You can do this even though your directory structure for css files may be several nested folders deep or in this case myproject/src/css/main.css . Django does not care about your directory structure. Django in general is quite loosely coupled from it's elements. For example, it's very easy to plugin another Pythonic templating language of your choice. Just as it's easy to set your STATIC_URL setting and STATIC_DIRS so Django knows where to look and it serves them all from /static/.